# Converting a class component ref to a functional component useRef hook

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, ref

How do I convert the following class component syntax to a functional component using useRef?

```
moveBody = index => {
      this.scrollRef.scrollTo({
        x: index * width,
        animation: false
      })
  }

<ScrollView pagingEnabled ref={node=>this.scrollRef=node}>
 ...
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [React Hooks `useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) documentation for details.

```js
const App = () => {
  const scrollRef = React.useRef(null);
  
  const handleClick = () => console.log(scrollRef.current)
  
  return <div ref={scrollRef} onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</div>
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I've tried this, but `scrollRef.current` results in `null` and therefore cannot do the portion for `scrollTo` that I want to convert.

Comment: It will be `null` on the first render because it hasn't been set yet.